# Why am I getting an error when loading webviews in VS Code 1.56?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using a portable install of VS Code 1.56.1 on Windows 10. Whenever open an extension from the marketplace, I get the following error:

> Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('vscode-webview://extensioneditor/') with script ('vscode-webview://extensioneditor/service-worker.js?platform=electron&id=extensionEditor&vscode-resource-origin=https%3A%2F%2FextensionEditor.vscode-webview-test.com'): ServiceWorker cannot be started.

Same thing happens for other things using webviews, with a slightly different path (like VS Code release notes). I'm able to install plugins and view the Feature Contributions tab, but I cannot view the Details and Changelog tabs.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this? This is on a managed machine where security settings might be changing. I'm using a portable install because my installed version stopped working out of the blue last week and this was supposed to be the workaround until that was figured out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem, in terminal use `code . --no-sandbox`

Updating python3 to the most recent version may also help.

Comment: This ended up working for me at the time. Seems like it may have had something to do with underlying changes in SandBoxing, and it not playing nicely with some VM/DaaS setups.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting the same error, it looks like an issue introduced on version 1.56.0.

For me the fix was running VS Code without elevated permissions.

I always run as administrator and running without it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my VS Code to newer version can solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think the issue in version 1.56 is the same as [the issue in 1.83](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77115862/11107541) if that's what you're talking about. I intentionally did not write my 1.82 issue answer here, and did not do any duplicate closing between these two questions.