# Why is VS Code 1.82 having issues opening webviews?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code 1.82, and when I try to open something that uses webviews, I sometimes get a notification with this error message:

> Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state..

Places where I've observed this problem include things like the builtin media preview extension, which allows viewing image files, the [`adpyke.codesnap`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.codesnap) extension, the builtin Markdown Preview functionality, the [`Postman.postman-for-vscode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Postman.postman-for-vscode) extension, the [`rangav.vscode-thunder-client`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client) extension, using the builtin `Simple Browser: Show` command, the list goes on.

It also seems to be that startup times for VS Code are slower when this issue happens, and that if VS Code starts up with more normal startup times, the issue doesn't happen.

This is not the same issue as the one in [Why am I getting an error when loading webviews in VS Code 1.56?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67505630/11107541). I am on VS Code 1.82 and not VS Code 1.56. I am not running VS Code with elevated privileges.

Why is this happening? How can I get things working again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting an error when loading webviews in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505630/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-loading-webviews-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with VS Code 1.82: [Webviews do not work 50% of the time after 1.82 update #192965](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192965).

According to [this comment by x-hgg-x](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192965#issuecomment-1729437073), the issue caused by another issue: [Update to 1.82.0, VSCode takes more time to kill processes after quit
#192742](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192742), which was caused by regressions related to telemetry. The workaround is to close all VS Code processes manually. The issue is currently fixed in the latest VS Code insiders.

The issue ticket is now closed as a duplicate of [Webview Service Worker Error in registration due to invalid document state (Linux)
#125993](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125993).

#### Other older information

Of what I've read from other users experiencing the issue and the workarounds they found:

- Some say that after getting the error notification, closing the webview and then reopening it works fine ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192965#issuecomment-1720646566)).
- Some users with this issue have observed that restarting VS Code is enough to make the problem "go away" ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192607#issuecomment-1712009069)).
- Some say restarting their computer helps ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192555#issuecomment-1711526872)), while others say it doesn't ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192965#issuecomment-1717048245)).

As for the connection to slow startup times, it's quite possibly related to this other issue ticket: [Slow startup time on 1.82.0 #192493](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192493) and the "init storage (global & workspace)" step of startup.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this problem after I updated VSCode to 1.84.2 (Ubuntu 22.04, installed via snap) when I try to load a jupyter notebook.
As suggested by ChatGPT, I emptied the cache of VSCode by removing the contents of these folders `~/.config/Code/Cache`, `~/.config/Code/CachedData` and `~/.config/Code/GPUCache`.
After a restart of VSCode, everything seems to work normally again.

Comment: ... interesting... this might suggest a relation to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77100725/11107541